# How to create new objects consisting of multiple cocoa touch objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uibutton, subclassing

I want to make a group of cocoa touch objects behave like one object, Is this possible?

For instance, say we had a SuperButton that consisted of two UIButtons, spaced by 10.
Let's just say their frame is set.

Is it possible to make a wrapper class ?

that I can init and call -

```
[_view addSubview:SuperButton] on and have it create both buttons?
```

I'm not entirely sure on the terminology for what I'm trying to do so it's hard to find any help on google.

Comment: Okay, Let me ask you this question first. So you want to create a SuperButton, when ever you call it it should layout the two buttons for you, is this right ?. YES you can do this. Create a new XIB, which is having just a view. configure your buttons in it. Create your super button class and assign it to this xib. You should be able to call this class and it will return view which can be added to your main view controller.

Comment: I want the buttons to be added directly to the main view though. Not sure if this matters though?

I just realized I could pass in the view as a parameter to the initializer and it could push all the buttons to that view from there. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: Nevermind, just played around with your idea and I like it. It's clean.

Comment: :) I use this approach when I need the same view to be presented in different sections of my app. So we basically write the code once use it many times. Even if we want to change , let's say add third button. Just add it t XIB. It will simply reflect in all other places.

Comment: I used Priyathams approach. I'm just wanting a matrix of UI Buttons and writing accessor methods for them... and different animations and stuff. Instead of calling some sort of [[_array objectAtIndex: #] objectAtIndex: #] every time I'm writing individual methods to do that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Let me ask you this question first. So you want to create a SuperButton, when ever you call it it should layout the two buttons for you, is this right ?. YES you can do this. Create a new XIB, which is having just a view. configure your buttons in it. Create your super button class and assign it to this xib. You should be able to call this class and it will return view which can be added to your main view controller.